# React making api calls with componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about making api calls with react.  They say to make them in the componentDidMount lifecycle method, but if the component is already mounted, do I have to re-render it again somehow?  What if I am making a get request and the component displays some data that it gets?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set state after making the request the component will rerender

This is actually why useEffect() in react hooks is both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate; a lot of people will correctly implement componentDidMount, but they'll forget to implement componentDidUpdate and you end up with components that you need to remount in order for them to function correctly when they should be responding to the changes in props via componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Thanks @JingGuo Gan!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! @Matt123

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `componentDidMount` for (automatic) initial API calls made on page load, you can still make any API calls via a user interaction like a button click etc.

Answer (score 0):

When your call completes within `componentDidMount`, set the state to store your result. This will trigger the component to rerender. If your component relies on information from an api call, consider using a loader and clearing it once the call is complete.